# Modify Input Dynamically to Search against data stored in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, querydsl

I am new to Elastic Search, have been reading a lot about it, but I stumbled at one requirement.

Consider a field of type *text* in all the *documents* in a *index* be "**app_data**"

Now **app_data** field always stores one word but that word can be an alphanumeric , numeric, alphabetic.

**Requirement -**

One type of word stored in **app_data** looks something like -

> `app_data:"99IPAB999999FG"`

Now if the user wants to search for this app_data they enter something like

> `"99.IPAB.99999.9"`

*Another Example* -
Data in index

> `app_data:"78IGDB900459JI"`
> User searches like -
> `"78.IGDB.90045.9"`

How should I form a ES query to match the data stored in the index docs if this is feasible?

**Considerations -**

1. I cannot edit the data (using a custom analyser) during insertion to the index as **app_data** can have simple words like "RED", "RED567".
2. Only for the problem mentioned above, I think I have to use a custom analyser along with query DSL.

Comment: you data in index is 99IPAB999999FG, which analyzer using in app_data? You want result 99IPAB999999FG when search by term 99.IPAB.99999.9? The "FG" not use? I imagine use the wildcard query in this case.

Comment: Answer to your first question - I haven't used any analyzer in that field. 
Answer to your other questions is "Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is already indexed and cannot be changed, my suggestion is that you apply a pattern before sending the term to the query, removing the ".", 99.IPAB.99999.9 -> 99ipab999999.

With this, you can successfully apply the [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html).

If you cannot apply the pattern to the input, you can do so at search-time "[search_analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html)".

The proposal will be to create a parser that generates the token without the ".".
In your query add "analyzer":"my_analyzer" that the token will be generated without the "." and the match will work.

New analyzer:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": """\.""",
          "replacement": ""
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "app_data": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
POST my-index-000001/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"app_data":"99IPAB999999FG"}
{"index":{}}
{"app_data":"78IGDB900459JI"}

POST my-index-000001/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
   "match_phrase_prefix": {
     "app_data": {
       "query": "78.IGDB.90045.9",
       "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
     }
   }
  }
}
```

Hits

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my-index-000001",
    "_id": "_jNxfoUBQB-6H-4Z6KWM",
    "_score": 0.6931471,
    "_source": {
      "app_data": "78IGDB900459JI"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your ans @rabbitbr .I don't want to use "my_analyzer" by default everytime i query this field. 
I might have a text like **"abcd.yyyy@gmail.com"**. Here i don't want to apply "my_analyzer" by default.

So can i ignore the mapping for that field you provided and do something like this dynamically everytime i query ? 
eg :
`POST my-index-000001/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "query": {
   "match_phrase_prefix": {
     "app_data": {
       "query": "78.IGDB.90045.9"
 "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
     }
   }
  }
}`

Comment: Yes, applying the analyzer in the query you will get the documents. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am getting closer, thanks, i am getting some exception while creating a index with that pattern. 
"pattern": """\."""
------------
Exception - "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "[1:97] Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: (byte[])\"

Comment: however i was able to create the index with other pattern, and search with my_analyzer and it worked - 
**"pattern":"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+"**
----
I only want to omit ".". But i think this is ommiting all punctuations and special characters. Any idea or modification to this or your pattern ?